# How to unpack Option[(Int, Int)] in Scala

Tags: scala

The following is a valid and readable piece of code to unpack returned values.

```
def func: (Int, Int) = (1, 2)

val (a, b) = func
```

What about the functions that return `Option`? For example:

```
def func2: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((1, 2))
```

How can I unpack this in a readable way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `(Int, Int)` is sugar for tuple type

```
Tuple2[Int, Int]
```

so `Option[(Int, Int)]` becomes

```
Option[Tuple2[Int, Int]]
```

thus correct syntax would be

```
val Some(Tuple2(a, b)) = func2
```

or

```
val Some((a, b)) = func2
```

or

```
val Some(a -> b) = func2
```

However mind if `func2` returns `None` then it will explode with `MatchError`. The reason becomes clear if we examine the expanded version which is something like

```
val x: (Int, Int) = func2 match {
  case Some((a, b)) => (a, b)
  // but what about None case ??
}

val a = x._1
val b = x._2
```

Note how we did not handle `None` case. For this reason such extraction is rarely done. Usually we map over the `Option` and continue working within the context of the `Option`

```
func2.map { case (a, b) => 
  // work with a and b
}
```

or we provide some default value if possible

```
val (a, b) = func2.getOrElse((0, 0))
```

Comment: I believe it would good to do more emphasis on the failure possibility of this operation, I would even mention it at the very beginning. A tuple is always total, so unpacking it makes sense. An **Option** is not, maybe it would be also good to include `getOrElse` in the answer.

Comment: Thank you both for the detailed explanation, especially about the failure possibility. I am using `for` comprehension and actually `func` returns `Future[Option[(A, B)]]`. So, the syntax will be like `for { Some((a, b)) <- func } yield b` for your solution. I guess, in this case, `getOrElse` can be used for handling the failures.

Comment: @Alperen yeah in that case you probably would want to do something like `func.map(_.fold(default)(_._2))` or if you want to be more verbose `func.map(opt => opt.fold(default) { case (_, b) => b }`